GeoServer configuration lock is enabled. Can I set this to disabled on startup?
I am trying to deploy kartoza/docker-geoserver. Everything seems to work but after logging in and trying to create a workspace I get a 400 Bad Request when I hit save and the POST call is made. I assume this is related to the config lock. Is there a ENV variable to set this to disabled when it is deployed?

I doubt it is a "config lock" - what does the log file say is actually the problem.

This is deployed on Google Cloud Run and I am trying to use PostgreSQL as the backend for the config files(jdbcconfig). I don't see anything in the log section of the web ui and when i try to download the full log file i get the 400 error. Google cloud run logs show this. POST4001.82 KB20 msChrome 122 https://geoserver-uc.a.run.app/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage?9-1.IFormSubmitListener-form&filter=false

Is the request even getting to GeoServer? or is this a Google Cloud issue? Please add the exact request you are posting and the URL and the full response that is returned.

It is. This is the log from the cloud run event.
{
httpRequest: {11}
insertId: "662f97390008228adc4a61a5"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/geoserver-dev/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-04-29T12:48:57.639151462Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "WARNING"
spanId: "349559552646440709"
timestamp: "2024-04-29T12:48:57.462635Z"
trace: "projects/geoserver-dev/traces/d4cf68872328519f4f4d0501a35ad637"
}

I am trying to save a workspace when I get the 400 error.
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
Type Status Report
Message Origin does not correspond to request
Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
Apache Tomcat/9.0.73

Missing a content-type header?

You need to whitelist your site in the CSRF protection filter - see the manual

This env var isn't used in the docker container though correct?

I don't know what the docker container does - but to get that error message you have a CSRF problem

Setting GEOSERVER_WHITELIST_DISABLED to true makes everything work but when I try to add a domain to the whitelist I am still unable to save any configuration settings.

do you get the same error or a different one? Have you dealt with CORS?

Ian, not sure why but I thought CORS was enabled by default. That with the domain in the whitelist fixed it all. Appreciate your help!
